# Show the image in a large div on clicking the image in a small div

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div class="blowup">
 <img src="images/products/3.jpg" alt="even Men Black Slim Fit Nehru Jacket">
</div>

<div class="thumbs-container">
 <img src="images/products/1.jpg">
 <img src="images/products/2.jpg">
</div>
```

I have two `div`s. `.blowup` is the large one while those in the `.thumbs-container` are small.

What I need is to show the image in the `.thumbs-container` into the `.blowup` on clicking the small image. How can I do this using JQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.thumbs-container img').click(function(){
```

**what should I add here?**

```
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the src of the clicked `img` and assigned it to `blowup img`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $blowup = $('.blowup img');
    $('.thumbs-container img').click(function () {
        $blowup.attr('src', this.src);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tzkv61ee/)

Answer (score 1):

***Try this code:***
[The JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/JarvisStark/re0wd3bz/1/)

Html:

```
<div class='blowup'>
    <img src="img3.png" alt="img3"/>
</div>

<div class="thumbs-container">
        <img src="img1.png" alt="img1"/>
        <img src="img2.png" alt="img2"/>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbs-container img').click(function(){
        $('.blowup img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

I think it will be helpful to you...!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blowup img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'))
```